# COCOA Objects Allocation/Deallocation + Memory Optimization

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Ah.. We've developed a good iPhone application. Now, 'm passing through last phases of it, i.e. profiling it and I've encountered few problems. Application has few leaks and objects occupying large memory chunks. We just checked somehow, application is not lowering its memory requirements and blocks remain occupied with creation of each View Controller.

Some of the views I really don't want after their disappearance, but they are not deallocated.

We're also downloading large files into iPhone through app but once we download very large file (> 10 MB), it crashes. Because after download we've also used thumbnail generation logic into which UIImage is created with 'contentsOfFile'..! So, app generally crashes after use of large files. We've used UIWebView for thumbnails.

My real problem is download, thumbnail, preview of larger files... clearing unnecessary memory (objects) once view is not in focus..!

Can anyone help me get rid of such problems easily???
I really don't wanna go through long long code..!

Thank You..!

Answer (score 1):

As has been written hundreds of times on SO, use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for networking, especially for large files. It can stream big files directly to disc so you don't run out of memory. As for creating a thumbnail of a >10mb file, it sounds like you would do yourself a favor by storing a thumbnail on the server instead.

If your views don't unload, something is wrong with your retain/release cycles. Have you implemented viewDidUnload on all your view controllers? Without more details, it's very hard to help.

Comment: As I said three months ago: "Without more details, it's very hard to help." Please read the SO faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq
In particular remember that questions should be"detailed and specific" and "written clearly and simply".